# Subpartitioned Index status is USABLE

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning

To my knowledge, an index can be VALID, INVALID,UNUSABLE, and N/A status. For a subpartitioned index, I see the status as USABLE instead of VALID. I could not find the reason for this status in anywhere. Please make me understand the reason behind this status.

I created a subpartitioned table. Created local index on it. Looked upon the status of index in all ind tables. It all had N/A. Only the all_ind_subpartitions table has USABLE status.

Comment: Please check the documentation of [ALL_IND_SUBPARTITIONS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_IND_SUBPARTITIONS.html):  `STATUS` - *Indicates whether the index partition is usable (USABLE) or not (UNUSABLE)*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply a difference in terminology. `USABLE` = `VALID`. For some crazy reason a different term is used at the partitioned segment level than at the index level. `N/A` means that the index is partitioned, so it can't represent the status at that higher global level because it could be a mix of usable and unusable. So, you have to look at the segment level (either `dba_ind_partitions` and/or `dba_ind_subpartitions` for composite partitioned indexes) view to see the actual statuses.

Here is where these statuses come from in Oracle's view definitions:

**DBA_INDEXES:**

```
   decode(bitand(i.property, 2), 2,
               decode(i.type#, 9, decode(bitand(i.flags, 8),
                                    8, 'INPROGRS', 'VALID'), 'N/A'),
                 decode(bitand(i.flags, 1), 1, 'UNUSABLE',
                        decode(bitand(i.flags, 8), 8, 'INPROGRS',
                                                        'VALID'))),
```

**DBA_IND_PARTITIONS:**

```
decode(bitand(ip.flags, 1), 1, 'UNUSABLE', 'USABLE'), ts.name,
```

**DBA_IND_SUBPARTITONS:**

```
decode(bitand(isp.flags, 1), 1, 'UNUSABLE', 'USABLE'), ts.name,
```

As we can see, `VALID` is simply a synonym for `USABLE`. There is no `INVALID` status anywhere. The flip of `VALID` is `UNUSABLE`.

If *any* subpartition of the index is unusable, the index will not be used unless the query is partition pruned. One would wish this could be reflected at the index level, but unfortunately Oracle chose not to do so. So if you are trying to figure out why an index isn't being used, make sure to check the `dba_ind_subpartitions` or `dba_ind_partitions` (if not composite partitioned) and look for any row with an unusable status. Rebuild whichever segment(s) are unusable to restore the index to usefulness.